# Why is this equation an odd function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

According to my textbook, the function $f(x)=x^9-3x^5+2x^2-10$ is odd.

My question is, why is it an odd function? If $x$ is replaced by $-x$, don't the first two terms change but not the second and third, making it neither even nor odd?

Thanks.

Comment: You're right, it isn't an odd function.

Comment: It is most certainly not an odd function. An odd function is defined as one that satisfies:$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$

Comment: Maybe they thought it looked weird. ;-)

Comment: Well, that your textbook would list it is very odd.

Comment: It's probably a typo.  I'd bet they meant: $f(x)=x^9-3x^5+2x^3-10x$ but that's a pretty severe mistake.

Comment: It doesn't even satisfy $f(0) = 0$, which is always true for an odd function.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a polynomial is odd by checking if each exponent in the polynomial is odd.
$$2x^2$$
$$-10x^0$$
These are even, so the function is not odd. Since the leading term is odd, the polynomial is neither even, nor odd.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted in the comments, this polynomial is *not* odd, for precisely the reason you mention. However, it's possible that what your textbook is actually saying is that this is an *odd-degree polynomial*, i.e. that its leading term is odd degree. While not every polynomial has even or odd symmetry, every polynomial *can* be classified as even or odd with respect to its leading term, and this classification tells you what the global behavior is for the polynomial.  Moreover you can make statements like "Every odd-degree polynomial has at least one real zero."